# High memory Usage on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, macos-big-sur

I am having trouble with high memory use on Mac OS Big Sur with Python 3.8 and Spyder.  It seems like I have around 12Gbyte free memory but when in Python it reports 85% usage.  I don't understand how to resolve these two apparently contradictory data.
From spyder:
{'total': 17179869184,
'available': 2548957184,
'percent': 85.2,
'used': 1383866368,
'free': 1515134976,
'active': 1036136448,
'inactive': 998625280,
'wired': 347729920}

and this is from Activity Monitor:

Physical: 16.00GB
Memory Used: 6.12GB

- App memory 3.64GB
- Wired 1.15GB
- Compressed 724MB
  Cached files: 4.25GB
  Swap used: 0

Comment: What are you using to get the memory usage in spyder?

Comment: same as the python code - ie 85% so I don't think its spyder related but seems a lot of variance for just python

Comment: Sorry if my comment was unclear, I meant to ask what program/tool you were using to measure the memory usage when you write _From spyder_. Also, it may be worth looking at the memory pressure metric in Activity Monitor, instead of the raw numbers for memory used/available (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/activity-monitor/actmntr1004/mac).

Comment: ha sorry - I am using psutil within python both at the command line and within a spyder interpreter  or the Activity Monitor is the MacOS built in tool.